# JSON div style background image link doesn't have slashes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am creating a list of thumbnails with JSON and I have problem with this line of code:

```
videoHTML += '<div class="user-background" style="background-image: url("' + video.channel.video_banner + '");">';
```

I can see `div` element and everything in it except `background-image` link doesn't have slashes.

This is the code that I see in debugger elements:

```
<div class="user-background" style="background-image: url(" https:="" static-cdn.jtvnw.net="" jtv_user_pictures="" esl_csgo-channel_offline_image-c9f885982daa1c83-1920x1080.png");"=""><div class="user-background" style="background-image: url(" https:="" static-cdn.jtvnw.net="" jtv_user_pictures="" esl_csgo-channel_offline_image-c9f885982daa1c83-1920x1080.png");"=""><img class="user-logo" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/esl_csgo-profile_image-546a0c1883798a41-300x300.jpeg" alt="user image"><p class="user-name">ESL_CSGO</p></div><a href="#" onclick="popup('esl_csgo')"><img class="video-image" src="http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_esl_csgo-320x180.jpg"></a><h1 class="game-name">Counter-Strike: Global Offensive</h1><br><i></i><span class="views-number">41304</span><p class="short-date-format date0">2012-06-11T13:36:21Z</p></div>
```

Can You help me by explaining what I am doing wrong with quotation marks?
(I believe that they are causing this problem.)

Here is the code for you to understand it better:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $.getJSON( "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams", function( data ) {
        var items = [];
        var videoHTML ='<ul>';
        //Get data and create video grid
        $.each(data.streams, function(i, video){ 
            if(i < 9) {  //get only first 9 data
                var videoDate = $.format.date(video.channel.created_at, "MMM dd yyyy");
                videoHTML += '<li class="video-stream ' + video.channel.language + '">';
                videoHTML += '<div class="user-background" style="background-image: url("' + video.channel.video_banner + '");">';
                videoHTML += '<img class="user-logo" src="' + video.channel.logo + '" alt="user image">';
                videoHTML += '<p class="user-name">' + video.channel.display_name + '</p>';
                videoHTML += '</div>';
                videoHTML += '<a href="#" onclick="popup(\'' + video.channel.name + '\')">';
                videoHTML += '<img class="video-image" src="' + video.preview.medium + '"></a>';
                videoHTML += '<h1 class="game-name">' + video.game + '</h1><br/>';
                videoHTML += '<i></i>';
                videoHTML += '<span class="views-number">' + video.viewers + '</span>';
                videoHTML += '<p class="short-date-format date' + i + '">' + videoDate + '</p>';
                videoHTML += '</li>';
                // var userId = "'#userBackground" + i +"'";
                alert(userId);
                // console.log(video._id);
                // console.log(data.streams[i].game);
                // console.log(data.streams[i]._links.self);
                // console.log(data.streams[i].preview.medium);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
        videoHTML += '</ul>';
        videoHTML += '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
        $('#placeholder').html(videoHTML);
    }); //getJson
}); //end ready
```

Comment: Where does 'video.channel.video_banner' come from?  Did you confirm that the slashes are there in that field if you put a breakpoint somewhere in this code block?

Comment: What slashes are you even talking about? Please show current output and expected results for that tag

Comment: Your code seems to work fine here https://jsfiddle.net/18ztohcf/. All I changed was `$.format`

Comment: omg that's horrible! all that `+=` is so 1989! `videoHTML = $('<ul />')` then simply something like `videoHTML.append($('<li />', { 'class': 'video-stream' }).addClass(video.channel.language).append($('<div />', { ...)` OR, you could maintain EZ variable control with something like `var li = $('<li />', { 'class': 'video-stream' }).addClass(video.channel.language).appendTo(videoHTML), div = $('<div />', { /*attributes*/ }).appendTo(li),  ...`

Comment: Thank You all for your contribution. Charlietfl can You tell me which $.format have You changed? (I see that it is working on js fiddle.)

Comment: SpYk3HH, thank You also for your enlightenment I will study it for sure. I have written the code as I was shown on treehouse.  (I am still junior...)

Comment: charlietfl I have checked jsFiddle again and it is not working properly.

Comment: @BotićDenis FYI, don't know if you saw, but I just updated my answer with your exact solution. But I'm leaving the rest for you to cmoe back and learn from. Feel free to hit me up with any questions!

Comment: Thank You a lot SpYk3HH, I have been studying your recommended code. Everything is working properly thanks to You! I will use this 1989 solution for now until I study everything.   Will save Your contact info for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***UPDATE*** I found your problem. You have to change the `"` around the `style` to `\'`. 
> Like so:

```
videoHTML += '<div class="user-background" style=\'background-image: url("' + $.trim(video.channel.video_banner) + '");\'>';
```

[See it working with your *corrected code* **here**.](https://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/qzsrfhgp/)

---

I rewrote the whole thing and showed you a few fundamental features of jQuery. Keep in mind, it's not necessarily *better*, per say, but perhaps more effecient and easier to follow. Within JS alone, there's a dozen different ways to write this. Within jQuery, a million. I could easily have made this a lot shorter, and if for myself, I would do it MUCH different. However, I hope this shows you some of the different uses of jQuery, as well as understanding on why variable control can be so important. I actually didn't see [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl)'s code working. The background still doesn't show up. However, as you'll see in my example, not only did I narrow down to the "*problem*", I also made it work, but not with anything fancy. I just used basic jQuery!

Keep in mind, [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/) has a well written, easy to follow [API](https://api.jquery.com/). Everything I use here is easily find-able [there](https://api.jquery.com/)!

### CodeSnippet

```js
function buildList(data) {
 if (data) {
  var videoHTML = $('<ul />'),
   clearFix = $('<div />', { 'class': '' }),
   items = [];
  $.each(data.streams, function(i, video){
   if(i < 9) {
    var videoDate = video.channel.created_at, // $.format.date(video.channel.created_at, "MMM dd yyyy"),
     li = $('<li />', { 'class': 'video-stream' }).addClass(video.channel.language).appendTo(videoHTML),
     div = $('<div />', { 'class': 'user-background' }).appendTo(li),
     imgLogo = $('<img />', { alt: 'user image', 'class': 'user-logo' }).attr('src', video.channel.logo).appendTo(div),
     pUser = $('<p />', { 'class': 'user-name', html: video.channel.display_name }).appendTo(div),
     a = $('<a />', { href: 'javascript:void 0' }).data('vidName', video.channel.name).appendTo(li),
     imgPrev = $('<img />', { 'class': 'video-image' }).attr('src', video.preview.medium).appendTo(a),
     h1 = $('<h1 />', { 'class': 'game-name' }).appendTo(li),
     br = $('<br />').appendTo(li),
     ita = $('<i />').appendTo(li),
     span = $('<span />', { 'class': 'views-number' }).html(video.viewers).appendTo(li),
     pDate = $('<p />', { 'class': 'short-date-format' }).addClass('date' + i).appendTo(li);
    
    // And now we can zero in on your issue with ez, by moveing that one thing here
    try {
     console.log(video.channel.video_banner);
     div.css('backgroundImage', 'url("' + video.channel.video_banner + '")');
    }
    catch(err) { console.log(err); }
   }
   else return false;
  });
  $('#placeholder').append(videoHTML, clearFix);
 }
}
$(function() { // jQuery shorthand for $(document).ready(function(){
 $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams", buildList);
  //  the following uses our STATIC element to assign click event to our DYNAMICALLY added anchors
 $('#placeholder').on('click', '.video-stream a', function(e) { popup($(this).data('vidName')); });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

### [jsFiddle for playing!](https://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/d6wnqd4g/)